# Combobox with search suggestions

Tags: performance, vba, excel

I created a combobox of which the list of options updates whenever you type in the box. Just a bit like entering a search in google works with suggestions.
I followed this tutorial to do so: https://trumpexcel.com/excel-drop-down-list-with-search-suggestions/

There are 4 columns of data in the sheet that make this work, combined with a named range, and a short piece of VBA to update the combobox. The combobox is in linked to cell B3. And data is in E:H starting at row 3.

- **First column** includes the options for the combobox. There are 5619 possible options to choose from.
- **Second column** has the following formula to determine if the entry of the combobox is in the text of the same row in the first column: `=--ISNUMBER(IFERROR(SEARCH($B$3,E3,1),""))`
- **Third column** has the following formula to establish the amount of matches found: `=IF(F3=1,COUNTIF($F$3:F3,1),"")`
- **Fourth column** has the following formula to return the list of possible options based on the value typed in the combobox: `=IFERROR(INDEX($E$3:$E$22,MATCH(ROWS($G$3:G3),$G$3:$G$22,0)),"")`

The code to update the combobox is as follows:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
ComboBox1.ListFillRange = "DropDownList"
Me.ComboBox1.DropDown
End Sub
```

With `DropDownList` Being a named range that selects all the names in the fourth column.

The problem I face here is purely performance. It is really slow and unresponsive on a PC. Let alone deployed on a mobile device, which I intend to.

The problem is ofcourse within the fact that there are 5600+ options for the combobox, and therefore 4*5600 formula's to be recalculated at every character entered in the combobox. I was wondering if there is a way to do with less helper columns, and maybe more VBA to reduce the calculation times required?

Comment: I feel that there at least should be a way to combine the second and third column into 1 column.

Comment: Just thinking out loud here. Maybe named ranges could do the trick here. Shortening the list of total options, by matching them only within a named range.

Answer (score 1):

To combine the second and third column into only 1 helper column I deviced the following formula's:

In the first cell of the second column I put the following formula: `=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($B$3,E3,1))=FALSE,"",--ISNUMBER(SEARCH($B$3,E3,1))`

In the second cell and down I wrote the following formula: `=IF(--ISNUMBER(IFERROR(SEARCH($B$3,E4,1),""))=0,"",COUNT($E$3:$E3)+1)`

Comment: I still wonder if a VBA option would be faster then this worksheet formula way.

Comment: The problem with using Excel formulas here is that everything always has to be calculated in full, even if it's apparent that it's not relevant there's no way to short-circuit it.

Comment: Actually these can be simplified. The first cell (**F3**) should have `=--ISNUMBER(SEARCH($B$3,E3,1))` ; the second cell (**F4**) should have `=F3--ISNUMBER(SEARCH($B$4E4,1)))` and then fill down. Skipping the `COUNT()` will help you out a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The final column's call to `MATCH()` is triggering some slowdown. The `0` parameter forces a linear search, so the whole thing takes time proportional to n^2 where n is the number of elements. This needs to be avoided. The list of count in column G (or wherever you put it, if you got them combined) is in monotonically increasing order, so it is permissible to use `1` or `true` as the third parameter to `SEARCH()`, causing it to perform a binary search -- but unfortunately it might pick any element with that value. In order to end up at the right spot, take advantage of the other feature of binary search: it picks the latest value less than or equal to the searched item. Tweak the value slightly and end up at the right spot!

```
=IF(ROWS($G$3:G3)<=MAX($G$3:$G$1000),
 INDEX($E$3:$E$22,1+IFERROR(MATCH(ROWS($G$3:G3)-0.5,$G$3:$G$22,1),0)),"")
```

This depends on a helper cell somewhere else, named `MaxOfColumnG`, which is just the `=MAX($G$3:$G$1000)` or whatever.

How it works: The list in column G ("third column") is something like

```
0
0
0
1
1
1
2
2
3
4
```

The formula in **H3** wants to find the first `1`. So we search for `0.5`. We find the largest value less than or equal to `0.5`, which ends up being the last `0`. Add on one more and we're at the right place. I had to change the `IFERROR` to an `IF` but we already know the max-index. In addition, the `IF()` will short-circuit and not perform the `MATCH()` unless it is necessary.

Comment: I figured out a speedup, don't know if it'll help much @luuklag